# How would I call this function of a class within a passed in reference of a vector of the said class

Tags: c++, c++17

```
void AnimatedObject::doPhysics(const std::vector<Block>& blocks)
{
    blocks[0].getName();

    
    applyGravity();
    
}
```

here is my function in my Class AnimatedObject.h file that is a child to Object

Class Block is also a child of Object.

```
class Player;
class Block : public Object 
{
public:
    Block() = delete;
    Block(Vector2D columnRow, Object::Type name, const GUI& gui);
    void update(Object::Command command, const Player& player1, const std::vector<Block>& blocks) override{}

    
private:

};
```

Here is my block class.

```
class GUI;
class Block;
class Player;
struct Vector2D
{
    int x;
    int y;

    friend bool operator<(const Vector2D& srcL, const Vector2D& srcR)
    {
        return srcL.x < srcR.x;
    }
};

class Object
{
public:
    enum class Command { up, down, left, right, attack, jump, NA };
    enum class Type
    {
        none,
        bridge_center,
        bridge_end,
        bridge_start,
        center_block,
        top_block,
        tree_background,
        water,
        water_shore,
        water_top,
        water_wall,
        water_wall_corner,
        player = 100,
        enemy = 200
    };

    Object() = delete;
    Object(Vector2D position, Type name, const GUI& gui);
    

    Vector2D getPosition() const;
    void setPosition(Vector2D newPosition);
    Vector2D getDimensions() const;
    Type getName() const;

    virtual void update(Object::Command command, const Player& player1, const std::vector<Block>& blocks) = 0;

protected:
    const Type name{ Type::none };
    Vector2D position{ 0,0 };
    const GUI& gui;
};
```

and here is my Object Class

```
Object::Type Object::getName() const
{
    return name;
}
```

here is the function I'm trying to execute.
I'm getting errors like

> C2248 'Object::name': cannot access protected member declared in class
> 'Object'"

and

> "use of undefined type 'Block'"

Comment: Why do you have so many forward references ?

Comment: Include headers instead of forward declaring a class

Comment: Note as you have inheritance storing objects in vector by value not by (smart) pointer will lead to slicing issue.

Comment: I'm going to defend the use of forward declarations.  It's perfectly fine to use them, and in large projects it can be a major factor in reducing compilation time.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] demonstrating your observation.